# How to tag named entities to prepare training data for custom named entity recognition with spacy?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to train spacy named entity recognizer on my custom dataset. I have prepared a python dictionary having **key = entity_type and list of values = entity name**, but i'm not getting any way using which I can tag the tokens in proper format.

I have tried normal string matching(find) and regular expression(search, compile) but not getting what I want.

for ex: my sentence and the dict I'm using are(this is the example)

```
sentence = "Machine learning and data mining often employ the same methods
and overlap significantly."

dic = {'MLDM': ['machine learning and data mining'], 'ML': ['machine learning'],
 'DM': ['data mining']}

for k,v in dic.items():
  for val in v:
    if val in sentence:
      print(k, val, sentence.index(val)) #right now I'm just printing 
#the key, val and starting index

output:
MLDM machine learning and data mining 0
ML machine learning 0
DM data mining 21

expected output: MLDM 0 32

so I can further prepare training data to train Spacy NER : 
[{"content":"machine learning and data mining often employ the same methods 
and overlap significantly.","entities":[[0,32,"MLDM"]]}
```

Comment: Don't know python, but before checking sentence convert the content to lower-case. after the first index thats greater than -1 break the loop and build a result object using the index and the string-length. this way you should get your desired result

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Michael I think I tried what you are trying to say but that also not working if I have more than 1 or 2 entity in the same sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build a regex from all values in your `dic` to match them as whole words and upon a match grab the key associated with the matched value. I assume the value items are unique in the dictionary, they can contain whitespaces and only contain "word" characters (no special ones like `+` or `(`).

```
import re

sentence = "Machine learning and data mining often employ the same methods and overlap significantly."

dic = {'MLDM': ['machine learning and data mining'], 'ML': ['machine learning'],
 'DM': ['data mining']}

def get_key(val):
    for k,v in dic.items():
        if m.group().lower() in map(str.lower, v):
            return k
    return ''

# Flatten the lists in values and sort the list by length in descending order
l=sorted([v for x in dic.values() for v in x], key=len, reverse=True)
# Build the alternation based regex with \b to match each item as a whole word 
rx=r'\b(?:{})\b'.format("|".join(l))
for m in re.finditer(rx, sentence, re.I): # Search case insensitively
    key = get_key(m.group())
    if key:
        print("{} {}".format(key, m.start()))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VRKHBW)

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor this is what i want you saved my day.